# Create XPath with dynamic variable in runtime (XSL version 1.0) -> then use it as select

Tags: mapping, xslt-1.0

I have already read some pages here about this topic but nothing matched my issue so far.
So my problem is that I need to create an xpath string dynamically and use that xpath string in the select of a "<xsl:value-of"-tag to select the appropriate value from the xml document. But instead it is showing the string of the xpath itself as shown below

So I have a simple XML Document (just a small example to show the issue. The original is much larger containing more fields)

```
<s0:RootNode>
    <s0:HEADER>
        <s0:DocumentDate>2022-10-13</s0:DocumentDate>
        <s0:DocumentID>123456</s0:DocumentID>
    </s0:HEADER>
</s0:RootNode>
```

Here I create the xPath string dynamically:

```
<!-- This ('DocumentID') will be a dynamic value later on --> 
<xsl:variable name="varField" select="'DocumentID'"/>
<!-- The output of that variable is the correct xPath 's0:HEADER/s0:DocumentID/text()' I want to use. -->
<xsl:variable name="xPath" select="concat('s0:HEADER/s0:',$varField,'/text()')" />
```

So my map

```
<Value>
   <xsl:value-of select="$xPath" />
</Value>
```

Will produce the output:

```
<Value>s0:HEADER/s0:DocumentID/text()</Value>
```

instead of:

```
<Value>123456</Value>
```

So how can I 'force' to select the value 123456 based on the generic xpath string instead of the xPath string itself?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, a few XPath 1.0 processors have EXSLT `dyn:evaluate` support, others allow a proprietary way to call into the underlying platform and XSLT/XPath implementation for dynamic compilation and evaluation of XPath expressions, so we really need to know which XSLT 1.0 processor exactly you use. Of course for a single step with an element using e.g. `*[local-name() = $name]` is often an easy workaround not requiring dynamic XPath evaluation.

Comment: We are using the BizTalk integrated 1.0 processor which unfortunately has no special version. But as you mentioned: using  *[local-name() = $varField] works like a charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just make the element name variable.  You might not need s0:RootNode.    Just adjust based on your context.

```
  <!-- This ('DocumentID') will be a dynamic value later on -->
  <xsl:variable name="varField" select="'DocumentID'"/>

  <xsl:variable name="test">
    <Value>
      <xsl:value-of select="s0:RootNode/s0:HEADER/s0:*[local-name() = $varField]" />
    </Value>
  </xsl:variable>
```